# Applying filters to ClearCase Dynamic views

Tags: clearcase

I have noticed the behavior of a Dynamic view is different than a web view with the following config spec:

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element * MYLABEL
element * /main/latest
```

With a web view, my view is filtered by `MYLABEL`.
But in Dynamic views, I always get the "latest" files.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on:

- the config spec of the dynamic view
  (you need to double-check if it is the same than the web view, with a `cleartool catcs`)
- the files you are considering (that LABEL might not be applied on *all* those files)
- how long the web view was updated: a web view is basically like a snapshot view: you might see those versions now, but if the label was moved, then a refresh might give you different result.

Beside that, there is no differences in the selected versions a web view or a dynamic view would return.

---

The [OP Kevin Zamora](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2521386/kevin-zamora) adds in the comments:

> I got it to work.
>
> The problem is that Clearteam explorer is slowwww... and if you work remotely, it could take forever (and we reportedly have a fast connection).
>   Even at work, it takes many seconds.
>
> Also, I notice that you have to kill the show version tree window and restart it completely. Sometimes the window doesn't update properly.

Comment: I got it to work. The problem is that Clearteam explorer is slowwww..and if you work remotely, it could take forever (and we reportedly have a fast connection).  Even at work, it takes many seconds. Also, I notice that you have to kill the show version tree window and restart it completely. Sometimes the window doesn't update properly.

Comment: @kevinzamora ok, i have included your conclusion in the answer.

Comment: @kevinzamora don't foget http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote and http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer for this answer of the previous ones I gave you.